# How do I fix chrome generating wrong <td> heights when using a table to assemble together an image

Tags: html, css

This is my first post here, sorry if my formatting sucks.

Trying to assemble image slices together inside a  to create the effect of a full size image. FF and edge both display the image correctly however chrome appears to be generating different  heights despite all images in the row having the same height (they do have different widths). The problem only occurs when giving the table a set width (and shrinking the image size to fit within the table )

[image]

[image]

Ive tried changing .img to height:100% but that just changes the  height to the full length of the original image warping it. Ive also tryed making  height 100% with no luck

please note that the image pieces all have different heights per row and different widths per column do hardcoding is not possible

```
<style>
    tr,
    td,
    table,
    img,
    tbody {
        padding: 0;
    }

    table {
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 300px;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OfAxJus.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/N1bcNYU.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qCkFcIW.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/xqBG6zQ.jpg"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bddCcSn.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7ySyHqq.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ulHRT4Q.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/reU0Gyr.jpg"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rBsFVNI.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ikub1e4.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0RVlEWg.jpgg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/v22RK32.jpg"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1nLECe5.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/R9hI0ka.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Bs8pQEY.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ndLkcTb.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What can i do to make it so chrome doesnt generate the different  heights?

Comment: Can you perhaps host the images somewhere so that they could be included in your post? I copied what you had and replaced it with different images and they seemed to display fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Add `border-collapse: collapse`. Does it work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: Hi and thanks! 
Have updated the original post.

Comment: @Justinas Sadly no

Comment: My guess it's a rounding error. I would however first ask: Why are you splitting the image in pieces in the first place? And why are you using a table?

Comment: @RoToRa sadly that is the requirement i've been given. How would i go about fixing a rounding error?

Comment: Always question requirements. On one hand, you need to understand that the boss/client wants in order to fulfill the task well, but also you need to be able to call out bad requirements. Blindly following bad requirements doesn't help anyone. Fixing the rounding error is probably not simple, because it's something that is "built into" the browsers rendering engine. Off the top of my head I can't suggest any specific solutions.